# Jquery datatable sorting and pagination not working while serverside true

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

When i give the "bServerSide": true , sorting and pagination are not working , when i remove then only it was working. Please give your suggestions, because i need to do server side operations

Comment: `bServerSide`, when set, means that the data is processed by a server, and returned to datatables for display.

Answer (score 0):

Could you include this option ( "bProcessing"   : true) in your datatable script like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "bProcessing"   : true
    "bServerSide": true,
    "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
  });
});
```

you may get the pagination and sorting function